# Android SDK take much disk space?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, sdk, space

I work by eclipse and android studio to develop game and upload it in play store , but the problem is the sdk that take too much disk space more than 40GB , my question :is it necessery to install all SDK ? Because i test my app on particular device.

Comment: Each Android Platform includes its own sdk. Just install the newest version and make sure the compiledSdkVersion in build.gradle targets this version

Answer (score 0):

40GB seems very steep but yes it is necessary

Comment: So i must install the all version of sdk android from 2.2 to 8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a physical device for debugging and not the emulators, you can uninstall installed Android API versions by opening tools > android > sdk manager and unchecking the packages you don't need.

I have a physical Pixel device running 8.0 I use for debugging, so I do not have the Oreo package installed on my machine. I have a few emulators running lower versions of Android that I have installed through SDK manager. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, i use my phone for debugging

Comment: yes, then go to tools > android > sdk manager and uncheck all the installed API versions that you don't need.

Comment: which versions that i need to install it ??